# What is annotation indexing?

Tags: java, annotations, seam3, deltaspike

In [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/catch/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/#client_usage.handles_exceptions) of Seam Catch manual it is said that

> The @HandlesExceptions annotation may be deprecated in favor of annotation indexing done by Seam Solder.

However, the [Seam Solder manual](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/solder/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/) not even has the "index" word in it - at least as far as I searched. Not even Google gave me some minimal explanation about this term. So, what is "annotation indexing" in this context? How does Seam Solder do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that Seam Solder could index all the annotation of these classes, so you don't need the @HandlesExceptions annotation anymore, only the @Handles anotations at method level will suffice in that case.